# What is the integral of $e^{x+e^x}$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

What is the integral of  $e^{x+e^x}$ ? I really just need to know how to get the answer rather than the answer. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?  Please show your efforts first on this site

Comment: We are integrating $e^x e^{e^x}$. Let $u=e^x$.

Comment: Oh dear, I was REALLY overthinking this problem. I wasn't even looking to reverse the adding of exponents when multiplying. I solved the problem after rewriting it as such. I had originally attempted substituting for u = x + e^x which was a tangled mess that didn't work out.

Answer (score 7):

Write $e^{x + e^x}$ as $e^x e^{e^x}$, and use the substitution $u = e^x$.